# Can't do math on ndarray::ViewRepr

Tags: rust

Rust playground listing [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6e6a26d543e19aded4d49c9e1e78165)

I'm using ndarray, I'm trying to do math using sections of arrays.  Here's an example that generates the error I'm seeing:

```
use ndarray::{Array1, Array2};

fn main() {
    let mut bob = Array2::<i16>::eye(3);
    let ralph = Array1::<i16>::ones([3]);
    for mut b in bob.outer_iter() {
        b += b + ralph;
    }
    println!("{}", bob);
}
```

This gives the error `` error[E0369]: cannot add `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<i16>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` to `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&i16>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` ``

What I had hoped for, was a version of `bob` with `ralph` added to each row.

Is there a way to do this short of just generating a new array element-by-element?

Comment: The error is actually very useful if I understand it correctly. The problem is that you are trying to add something to a non mutable `ViewRepr` I think at least.

Comment: So how do I make it appropriately mutable?

Comment: You could use `for b in bob.outer_iter_mut() {` but as I tried in the playground that doesn't fix the error yet. Usually when you have a function like `.iter()` it also has a mutable iterator function `.iter_mut()`.

Comment: Does doing `let bob = bob + ralph;` instead of the for loop do what you wanted?

Comment: T'oh!  The dang thing is smarter than I thought!  That's the answer -- see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c1fac9eea691fdb4cb25227112bdbda) for a working example.  Put it down in the answer selection & I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bob.outer_iter()` goes through the values one by one providing an immutable reference to them. To be able to mutate we have to use `bob.outer_iter_mut()`.

Having said that I don't think that is what you want. There is a simpler way to add together `ndarrays`:

```rust
use ndarray::{Array1, Array2};

fn main() {
    let mut bob = Array2::<i16>::eye(3);
    let ralph = Array1::<i16>::ones([3]);
    let sue = bob + ralph;
    println!("{}", sue);
}
```

Comment: After one of your comments above I tried `bob.outer_iter_mut()`, and was still meeting defeat -- but code similar to the above does it for me, even with a much more complicated example.